# How to clear the jump on White Land II?

Tags: f-zero

I've been playing F-Zero a lot lately, along with a bunch of other "retro" games. I'm having a bit of trouble on the course "White Land II" in the Queen Cup. The course contains a slippery turn, followed by a long jump shown below.

[image: the jump on WL II]

I'm using the Fire Stingray which, as some may know, has a high top speed but somewhat low acceleration. I think the problem is that it is close to impossible to attain enough speed given such a small straightaway.

How to clear this jump? For reference, I attempted the jump at approximately 379 kilometers per hour, with no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold the down arrow on the D-Pad! Do this on any jump (and continue to hold down until you land) - you'll fly further and maintain top speed when you land

Comment: In later games you lose speed while holding down, so you need to wait until just before landing to press down. Sometimes holding down is necessary (For example, really long jumps or when using heavy machines that have a low air time)

Answer (score 1):

Cut the inside of the previous really hard and use a boost.

See it done on youtube:

Comment: This will most likely help. Although, what am I to do on the first lap when I have no boost?